# Prepared statement without question mark placeholder

Tags: java, jdbc

Is prepared statement without question mark placeholder still secure?

Example:

```
String username = "userename from EditText";
String password = "password from EditText";

PreparedStatement statement = _con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+password+"';");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: First you should define what you mean by "secure". I assume you mean "safe against SQL injection attacks" - in which case no, your code is absolutely not safe... and you possibly should look deeper into understanding what SQL injection attacks are, how they come about, and why parameterized SQL protects against them.

Comment: No, your example completely defeats the purpose of parameterized querying.

Comment: Try this: `String username = "'; DELETE FROM users; --";`. Or rather **DON'T** try that, but try to see what SQL you get. The SQL will **delete every record** in the `users` table.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, against SQL injection attacks. Thanks for answer. I tought It's not safe.. I just wantet to be sure.

Comment: As a side note: Depending on your DBMS, using markers will also help the server. If you send a SQL with `where id = 121324` and another with `where id = 234723`, then the server has to parse and optimize each statement separately. With `where id = ?`, both calls use same SQL, so server can *reuse* the access plan. Some SQL statements are huge, so parsing and optimizing (find access plan) can be relatively costly. Of course, missing an index is worse, but still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not secure (against SQL Injection). This is the same as using `Statement` and you have no improvement whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why prepared statements are more secure is that the mechanism which replaces the placeholders with your arguments  will escape them securely (replace the dangerous stuff with safe stuff)

Also the whole reason for using prepared statements is to allow the database to preprocess them , which means that you should only do one prepared statement with placeholders and then reuse it with different arguments to get the benefit.

Comment: Most implementations of parametrized queries do not need to escape values at all, as they are sent separately from the query, and their format in the protocol remove the need for escaping.

Comment: yeah well, then the protocol does the "escaping"